# Assigning "Actions" to objects

Tags: c#

I'm developing a library in which I have two groups of classes:

A) a couple of classes with a bunch of functions, or "actions", already written in code

B) a few classes which must be "configured" when instantiated, in a way that the user using my library can instantiate objects from this second group of classes and "assign" actions from the first group

Right now I'm using delegates, like this:

Somwhere in the code I declare some delegates that are used by A and B:

```
public delegate void Action03(int value);
```

Then I have the "actions" implemented in the group A:

```
public Delegates.Action03 DoSomething03 = delegate(int value) { [code to execute when this action is specified on the constructor] };
```

And finally we use constructors like the following to instantiate objects from group B, where we pass as arguments the delegates/actions that we want:

```
public SomethingGroupB(Delegates.Action03 act03) { ... }
```

So of course, we can instantiate objects passing delegates as arguments:

```
SomethingGroupB somthg1 = new SomethingGroupB(GrpA01.DoSomething03);
```

But the whole point is that we can instantiate similar objects but assigning different actions:

```
SomethingGroupB somthg2 = new SomethingGroupB(GrpA07.DoSomething03);
SomethingGroupB somthg3 = new SomethingGroupB(GrpA01.DoSomething01);
SomethingGroupB somthg4 = new SomethingGroupB(GrpA02.DoWhatever);
```

So... as a summary, I want to have pre-coded (in my library) actions, and the user must choose the actions assigned to a new object when it is instantiated, and those actions don't change.

I guess I could also do it with events, but I don't need to add and remove "actions", they are fixed for the whole life of each object of type B.

So my question is: is there a better, nicer, cleaner solution than this one I've implemented with delegates?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my question is: is there a better, nicer, cleaner solution than this one I've implemented with delegates?

The one improvement I would suggest would be to use the delegates defined in the framework, and not define your own.  For example, your `Action03` delegate is just a [`System.Action<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx).  This would provide a bit more usability in terms of making the API more discoverable.

That being said, this is effectively using delegates to implement the [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).  Provided this provides the full functionality you need, it is potentially a good option here, and rather clean.

Comment: Thank you very much. `System.Action<int>` looks like the right solution, but... what about actions/delegates that must return a value?

Comment: @Felko You'd use `System.Func<TResult>`, `System.Func<T,TResult>`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think delegates is the only way to go.

Maybe you could also use a decorator pattern if it suits your need ? Its pretty clean, and because its a pattern, its standard, and "easy" to understand as its in some way normalized.

Cant think of any other way, appart maybe from having a heavier use of object composition (and then linking your objects together at runtime, which may be a bit more suple ?